# Why do I get `Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object `?

Tags: loop, pagination

```
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'be_home_loop' );
    define('PER_PAGE_DEFAULT', 2);
function be_home_loop(array $query = array()) { 
     global $wp_query;
        wp_reset_query();
         $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
         $defaults = array(
                'paged'                         => $paged,
                'post_type' => 'blog_posts',
                'posts_per_page'        => PER_PAGE_DEFAULT
        );
        $query += $defaults;

        $the_query = new WP_Query($query);
}

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
wp_reset_postdata(); 
 else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is for the line of code: `if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>`

Please can someone  help, please?

This is for an archive page for a custom post type. So I need to query the custom post type, & I would like pagination to  work for more than two posts.

Comment: You simply got a problem with your scope. Rule of thumb: You only have access to variables defined in your current scope. And `$query` is defined (and therefore only exists) in the functions scope, not in your global one where you ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

to

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

#### Why?

When you call `$the_query = new WP_Query($query);` you're storing the loop in a variable called `$the_query`. `$query` is an array of arguments that you're passing to the new `WP_Query()` function. `$the_query` is a class and `have_posts()` and `the_post()` are methods which are basically functions specific to that WP_Query class.